# Casting to a bounded type

Tags: java, generics

I have a class hierarchy where cousins share very similar functionality. For example:

```
Node
  Statement
    FunctionCallStatement
  Expression
    FunctionCallExpression
```

FunctionCallStatement and FunctionCallExpression share a very similar API, but I cannot express that in pure class terms with a single-inheritance hierarchy. So, I've created an IsFunctionCall Interface which both of these implement. I can now declare a method which takes either a FunctionCallStatement or a FunctionCallExpression as follows:

```
void <T extends Node & IsFunctionCall> doSomething(T node) { ... }
```

This all works very nicely.

Unfortunately, I've now found myself faced with a rather awkward problem. I have a Node; I know dynamically that it *must* be either a FunctionCallStatement or a FunctionCallExpression; I need to pass that Node into the `doSomething()` method above. I cannot find a way to upcast it to an appropriate type.

Right now I'm using a chain of instanceof to determine which class the Node is and to cast it to the appropriate concrete type, but that's butt-ugly. The only other way I know to make this work is to make an IsNode interface and have everything that currently expects a Node expect an IsNode instead; this would allow me to declare a union interface that implements IsNode and IsFunctionCall and let me do away without the generics above. But that's a hell of a lot of work and is still pretty ugly.

Is there an alternative way to do this?

(Note: example above is a simplified version of my actual code.)

**Update:** I tried the following piece of evil:

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
private <S extends Node & IsFunctionCall> S castNode(Node node)
{
    return (S) node;
}
```

and then:

```
doSomething(castNode(node));
```

I got some *very* strange error messages. It would appear that the type inference used to determine the S of `castNode()` will not match against the T in the declaration of `doSomething()`; it's using the concrete type only and setting S to Node. Which of course does not match `doSomething()`'s declared type. Very peculiar.

**Update update:**

This appears to be a close duplicate of [How should I cast for Java generic with multiple bounds?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/318208/how-should-i-cast-for-java-generic-with-multiple-bounds). My situation is slightly different because my bounds include an object and an interface, while the one in the other question has two interfaces, but it's still applicable.

Looks like I need to go and reengineer my entire application. Sigh.

Any admin, feel free to close this as a duplicate...

Comment: possible duplicate of [How should I cast for Java generic with multiple bounds?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/318208/how-should-i-cast-for-java-generic-with-multiple-bounds)

Answer (score 0):

I think the way out of this, although not exactly elegant, is to have a few overloads for doSomething:

```
void doSomething(FunctionCallStatement node) ...
void doSomething(FunctionCallExpression node) ...
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using the interface to flag functionality, how about passing as argument a reference to the `FunctionCallInterface` which offers access to the function call abstraction?

`doSomething` won't have to know the actual implementation type as long as it can access the relevant information and call relevant methods on the implementation objects.

```
public class FunctionCallStatement extends Statement implements FunctionCallInterface {
}

void doSomething(FunctionCallInterface node) {
}
```

Comment: `doSomething()` needs to access Node functionality as well as FunctionCallInterface functionality, hence the reason for the generic type. I suppose I could pass in a Node *and* a FunctionCallInterface, although they will both end up being the same object...

Comment: @David Given, you could define a `NodeInterface` which `Node` implements and let the `FunctionCallInterface` extend that so that it supplies all functionality you need.