# Anonymous extending a class and implementing an interface at the same time?

Tags: java, anonymous-class

Suppose I have an interface called Interface, and a concrete class called Base, which, to make thing a bit more complicated, has a ctor that requires some arguments.

I'd like to create an anonymous class that would extend Base and implement Interface.

Something like

```
 Interface get()
 {
     return new Base (1, "one") implements Interace() {};
 }
```

That looks reasonable to me, but it doesn't work!

(P.S: Actually, the Interface and Base are also generic classes :D. But I'll ignore that for now)

Comment: Generic stuff may become nightmares if there is too much abstraction. Keep it simple ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This scenario makes little sense to me. Here's why: assume class `Base` is this:

```
class Base {
    public void foo();
}
```

and `Interface` is this:

```
interface Interface {
    public void bar();
}
```

Now you want to create an anonymous class that would be like this:

```
class MyClass extends Base implements Interface {
}
```

this would mean that `MyClass` inherits (or possibly overrides) method `bar` from `Base` and must implement method `foo` from `Interface`. So far so good, your class has these two methods either way.

Now, think what happens when you are returning an object of type `Interface` from your method: you only get the functionality that `Interface` offers, namely method `foo`. `bar` is lost (inaccessible). This brings us down to two cases:

1. Extending `Base` is useless because you do not get to use its methods, since the new object is seen as an `Interface`.
2. `Interface` also has a method `foo`, but that would mean that `Base` itself should implement `Interface`, so you can just extend `Base` directly:

> ```
> class Base implements Interface {
>     public void foo();
>     public void bar();
> }
>
> class MyClass extends Base {
> }
> ```

Comment: Well, I guess the intent of "implements Interface" was merely to perform a cast. I'll use concrete examples. I have a ViewClass that extends Collection class. Then I use this ViewClass to implement key-set and value-set. Suppose I somehow got all the implementations to be in ViewClass, which means, I technically do not need to put in any extra code for either the Key set or value set. The only one thing left to take care of is the type. Obviously keySet() has to return a set, while values() has to return a Collection.  So, to put it another way, can I just do [return (Set<K>)new Base(...)] ?

Comment: In what way is `MyClass` anonymous? It's got a name!

Comment: @Jon Skeet, precisely, I used a name so I can refer to it in the explanation.

Comment: @Tudor: But then it's not anonymous. You claim this is a way of creating an anonymous class - it's not, and I believe if you try to show a version which *actually* uses an anonymous class, you'll fail to get any working syntax.

Comment: @Jon Skeet: This was not the point of my post. I was not commenting on how to create what he wants, I was arguing that his class structure does not make sense.

Comment: @user1064918: Note that this post does not imply that you can just do `return new Base` if you need an explicit constructor. You will still need to do something like what Jon Skeet said, but I'm arguing that maybe you need to rethink your class structure.

Comment: Not to necro-thread, but there are valid uses of this.  One use would be to use an interface to gate access to parts of the base class, but it's impossible for the base class to actually declare that it implements the interface (generics).

Comment: there are scenarios when extending from an abstract class and implementing an interface makes a lot of sense. For instance CellEditor and TableCellEditor respectively

Comment: This "answer" is both wrong (as some commenters have pointed out, the scenario does indeed make sense in some cases) and not an answer (it does not explain whether doing what the OP asked about is possible and/or how to do it).

Comment: This scenario make sense, just suppose, i need to call methods of super class from method of my interface and using result in business logic in interface method.

Answer (score 15):

No, you can't do that with an anonymous class. You can create a named class within a method if you really want to though:

```
class Base {
}

interface Interface {
}

public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        class Foo extends Base implements Interface {
        };

        Foo x = new Foo();
    }
}
```

Personally I'd usually pull this out into a static nested class myself, but it's your choice...

Comment: @user1064918: It's rarely used, and for good reason - it's hard to read.

Comment: @JonSkeet I have this set up, I don't know of another way to do than to utilize named classes inside a method. They are only used to make the type-cast satisfy the expected type. https://gist.github.com/imminent/5248440 I'm curious if you know of another way, or think that's a fine legitimate use of named classes with a method.

Comment: EDIT: Actually, is this a way to type-case to satisfy extending multiple interface/classes?

Comment: @DandreAllison: I see no reason to use named classes in a method there - it would be fine with anonymous classes as far as I can tell.

Comment: @JonSkeet thanks, you're right, before I had tried casting in which I needed a name. But unfortunately it seems you have to delegate instead, so naming it just lets me split the declaration while keeping it scoped inside the method, but isn't necessary.

Comment: Be aware that when you declare and create a class `C` (named or anonymous) within a method `m` then you can indeed use local variables declared within `m` and outside `C` as long as those variables are final or effectively final. Imagine if a local variable `v` in `m` referred to from `C` is not final and its value changes after an instance of `C` has been created. How should that affect the value of `v` referred to inside the instance of `C`, especially considering that `v` is local and discarded when the method `m` is completed. Allowing final variables does make sense though.