# Strange Java cast syntax using &

Tags: java, casting, java-8, type-bounds, bounded-types

(Actually, this question is not directly related to lambdas, but to *casts* using bounds, so the question marked as duplicate does not provide an answer to this question. You'll find the answer to *my* question here: [How should I cast for Java generic with multiple bounds?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/318208/how-should-i-cast-for-java-generic-with-multiple-bounds))

Just recently, I took part in a SW craftsmanship meeting. In one of the discussed examples, I encountered kind of this cast, it seems to be valid Java since Java 8.

```
Object aTest = (String & CharSequence) "test";
```

My question: Can anybody tell me the idiom behind this and what it exactly can do for us? The presenter of the example couldn't explain it and I didn't find any mention (I don't even know a name for it).

**I have to put another answer here, in addition to Oleksandr's**, because this question was already marked as duplicate and thus is locked.

Meanwhile I was able to construct a (contrived) use case, just to make the idea clear.

Assume we have the generic method `foo()`, which is generic on its only parameter, and the type parameter has two upper bounds (against `Comparable` and `Serializable`):

```
public static <T extends Comparable & Serializable> void foo(T t) {
    System.out.println(t);
}
```

Further assume, we have a class `AClass`, which implements `Comparable` and `Serializable`

```
public class AClass implements Comparable, Serializable {
    @Override
    public int compareTo(Object other) {
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Further assume the contrived part, where we have an `AClass` object `instance`, which is assigned to a variable of type `Object`:

```
Object instance = new AClass();
```

If, in another place of the code, we want to pass `instance` to `foo()`, and we don't know the dynamic type of `instance` (which is `AClass`), we can use a special cast syntax to place a "contact lens" on `instance` to make the call work:

```
foo((Comparable & Serializable) instance);
```

Actually, the specialty is not in the cast syntax, but on how the type is specified. This type specification declares a so-called **intersection type**.

Comment: Java supports [*multiple bounds*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/bounded.html) for type parameters.

Comment: Yes, I know & from type bounds, but here is no type parameter involved.

Comment: Actually, that is what is happening here. It's ***mostly*** useful with the lambda `->` notation.

Comment: Elliott, can you point me to an example?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/14469627/2970947

Comment: `SortedSet<String> set = new TreeSet<>((Comparator<String> & Serializable) (a, b) -> a.length() - b.length());`: without the cast, the TreeSet wouldn't be serializable, because its comparator wouldn't be.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's a [cast operator](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.16) that can contain a list of types:

```
(ReferenceType {AdditionalBound}) Expression  =>  (String & CharSequence) "test";
```

Where `AdditionalBound` is defined as:

```
... & InterfaceType
```

---

> I'm understanding this generally, but what about a use case?

This [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22807912/how-to-serialize-a-lambda) and the answers describe a real practical use case. For example, to make a lambda expression serializable, you can write:

```
Consumer<String> consumer = (Consumer<String> & Serializable) System.out::println;
```

(thanks to @assylias)