# How to declare object of type class with multiple bounds

Tags: java

I have an object of type `Class<?>` and I'm trying to call a method with the signature:

```
<T extends A & B> void foo(Class<T> clazz);
```

How can I declare the argument to satisfy the signature?

---

*Example:*

```
void bar(String type) throws Exception {

    Class<?> clazz = Class.forName(type);

    if(!clazz.isAssignableFrom(A.class)) throw new IllegalArgumentException("type="+type);
    if(!clazz.isAssignableFrom(B.class)) throw new IllegalArgumentException("type="+type);

    //We know clazz implements both A and B, how do we call foo?
    foo(clazz.asSubclass(???)); 
}

<T extends A & B> void foo(Class<T> clazz) {
    //Success
}
```

---

*Edit: I resorted to refactor the `foo` method into `<T extends A> ...` and moved the `.isAssignableFrom(B.class)` inside it.*

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/33048780/1015327

Comment: @JimmyB casting with multiple bounds only works if the second bound is an interface. In my case the cast would be `(Class<A> & Class<B>)`, and although `B` is an interface, `Class<B>` is not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit: Let me preprend my answer with this (see below for more info): reflection and generics aren't a good fit as they operate at different times:

- generics primarily are a compile time tool to help the compiler spot potential programming errors such as trying to add strings to a list of numbers
- reflection primarily is a runtime tool to get information about your classes/objects at runtime (such as `resolveClass()`) and due to type erasure most generics information is lost at runtime

Original answer:

`T extends A & B` only works if `B` is an interface (A can be a class or an interface) and the parameter must match both, i.e. it must be a subclass of `A` *and* implement `B` (assuming `A` doesn't already implement `B` in which case the `A & B` part would be unnecessary).

As an example let's use `Number` and `Comparable`:

```
<T extends Number & Comparable<T>> void foo(Class<T> clazz);
```

We could now call `foo(Long.class)` because `Long extends Number implements Comparable<Long>`.

We couldn't call `foo(AtomicInteger.class)` because `AtomicInteger extends Number` *but it doesn't* implement `Comparable<AtomicInteger>`.

We also couldn't call `foo(Number.class)` because `Number` matches `extends Number` but doesn't implement `Comparable<Number>`.

In your case you'd need to define a variable `Class<? extends A & B>` but **that is not supported** so you'd need to use a generic type (defined on the calling method or the class) or a concrete type:

```
<T extends A & B> bar() {
  Class<T> clazz = resolveClass(); //This would need the same generic type
  foo( clazz );
}
```

or

```
class C extends A implements B {}
```

and

```
Class<C> clazz = resolveClass(); //This would need the same generic type
foo( clazz );
```

As you can imagine that can become quite complex and might not be feasible.
As a last ditch effort you could try to use raw types:

```
Class clazz = resolveClass(); //This would need the same generic type
foo( clazz );
```

This would produce a lot of warnings because it disables type checks so make sure your parameters are thoroughly checked. So if you need to do that it might hint at a design flaw so I'd suggest you think really hard about whether you need `T extends A & B` at all and what your code is doing.